# ISTQB Foundation Level Test Analyst

Tags: istqb

1. How long one should prepare/study before taking the ISTQB foundation level exam ?
2. Is one month enough ?

Comment: Certainly that depends on your experience and ability. I know folks who passed the exam with no preparation. And I know folks who spent months preparing and didn't pass.  Check out the sample questions at http://www.istqb.org/downloads/category/15-foundation-level-exam-documents.html. Plan your preparation time based on the level of difficulty you have answer the sample questions.